# Update Record w/o Changing Current Image

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi im new to PHP and im trying to update a record without changing the image. I tried many things but failed.
When its updating using the current image, it gives the error of "allowed image extensions", otherwise it works well when im adding a new image.
Can you help

Thanks

```
    <?php 

$getIdfromUrl = $_GET['id']; 


if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {

    $titlePost = $_POST["PostTitle"];
    $categoryPost = $_POST["Category"];
    $Admin = "admin";
    $file= $_FILES['Image'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['Image']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['Image']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['Image']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['Image']['type'];   
    
    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName); 

    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt)); 

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png','gif','tiff'); // allow specific extensions

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {

        if ($fileError === 0 ) {

            if ($fileSize < 3000000) {

                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt; //uniqueid 
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;                
                
            } else {
                $_SESSION["errorMessage"]= "Image Size No More Than 3MB"; 
                redirect_To("posts.php");                       
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION["errorMessage"]= "Something with the Image";
            redirect_To("posts.php");
        }

     else {
        $_SESSION["errorMessage"]= "Allowed jpg,jpeg,png,gif only";
        redirect_To("posts.php");
     }
}
    $textPost = $_POST["PostDescription"];
        
    $currentTime=time();
    $dateTime = strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H: %M: %S",$currentTime);
    $connectingDB;
            
    if (!empty($_FILES['Image']['name'])) {
       $sql="UPDATE posts SET title='$titlePost', category='$categoryPost', post='$textPost', 
       datetime='$dateTime', image='$fileNameNew' WHERE id='$getIdfromUrl'";
    } else {
        $sql="UPDATE posts SET title='$titlePost', category='$categoryPost', post='$textPost', 
        datetime='$dateTime' WHERE id='$getIdfromUrl'";
    }
```

$Execute = $connectingDB->query($sql);
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: You are only differentiating between the two cases at the very end, by checking whether `$_FILES['Image']['name']` is empty or not - you need to do this earlier (or repeat the same check in multiple places), so that the check for an allowed file suffix, also only happens when this was not empty.

Comment: hanks @tadman for th information. CBroe ok i moved the empty string above the if (in_array) and it worked, but why it doesnt update the current post description and datetime but it updates an empty string?